# How to simulate Word 2010-style Options category selector

Tags: delphi, button, ms-office

The Options dialog in Word 2010 implements the category selector via set of white "toggle" buttons that become orange when clicked (selected).

[image: Category selection in the Word 2010 Options dialog]

How would one re-implement such behavior in Delphi? A conformance with the current Windows theme is required (i.e. it must be possible to specify the button color as clWindow, not clWhite).

EDIT: To clarify - I only have problems with the category selector on the left. Everything else is fairly simple.

Comment: XE2, although I wouldn't know why what should make much difference.

Comment: Do you insist on making your own component(s) or are you interested in existing ones that have this kind of functionality?

Comment: Again I was not clear enough - I would rather reuse an existing component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the  [TButtonGroup](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ButtonGroup.TButtonGroup) component.

Using VCL Styles is by far the easiest solution but as like you said, using styles in XE2 is quite uncomfortable, in my opinion this feature only really became viable in XE3.

Per your request to use the default painting methods I'm submitting my solution,

source code of the project available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vedoahe6vixvuy/TButtonGroupPV.rar).

This project requires an image, the image is zipped together with the project.

*Compiled and tested in XE4.*

[image: Example of TButtonGroup with custom visual effects]

---

---

```
type

  TButtonGroup = class(Vcl.ButtonGroup.TButtonGroup)
   protected
     procedure Paint; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ButtonGroup1: TButtonGroup;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure ButtonGroup1DrawButton(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer;
      Canvas: TCanvas; Rect: TRect; State: TButtonDrawState);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MBitmap : TBitmap;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TButtonGroup.Paint;
var
  R : TRect;
begin
   inherited;
   R := GetClientRect;
   R.Top := Self.Items.Count * Self.ButtonHeight;
   {Remove the clBtnFace background default Painting}
   Self.Canvas.FillRect(R);
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonGroup1DrawButton(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer;
  Canvas: TCanvas; Rect: TRect; State: TButtonDrawState);
var
  TextLeft, TextTop: Integer;
  RectHeight: Integer;
  ImgTop: Integer;
  Text : String;
  TextOffset: Integer;
  ButtonItem: TGrpButtonItem;
  InsertIndication: TRect;
  DrawSkipLine : TRect;
  TextRect: TRect;
  OrgRect: TRect;

begin

    //OrgRect := Rect;  //icon
    Canvas.Font := TButtonGroup(Sender).Font;

      if bdsSelected in State then begin
         Canvas.CopyRect(Rect,MBitmap.Canvas,
                         System.Classes.Rect(0, 0, MBitmap.Width, MBitmap.Height));
         Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(255,228,138);
      end
      else if bdsHot in State then
      begin
        Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(194,221,244);
        Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;

      end
       else
        Canvas.Brush.color := clWhite;

      if not (bdsSelected in State)
      then
        Canvas.FillRect(Rect);


      InflateRect(Rect, -2, -1);


    { Compute the text location }
    TextLeft := Rect.Left + 4;
    RectHeight := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top;
     TextTop := Rect.Top + (RectHeight - Canvas.TextHeight('Wg')) div 2; { Do not localize }
    if TextTop < Rect.Top then
      TextTop := Rect.Top;
    if bdsDown in State then
    begin
      Inc(TextTop);
      Inc(TextLeft);
    end;

    ButtonItem := TButtonGroup(Sender).Items.Items[Index];

    TextOffset := 0;

    { Draw the icon  - if you need to display icons}

//    if (FImages <> nil) and (ButtonItem.ImageIndex > -1) and
//        (ButtonItem.ImageIndex < FImages.Count) then
//    begin
//      ImgTop := Rect.Top + (RectHeight - FImages.Height) div 2;
//      if ImgTop < Rect.Top then
//        ImgTop := Rect.Top;
//      if bdsDown in State then
//        Inc(ImgTop);
//      FImages.Draw(Canvas, TextLeft - 1, ImgTop, ButtonItem.ImageIndex);
//      TextOffset := FImages.Width + 1;
//    end;


    { Show insert indications }

    if [bdsInsertLeft, bdsInsertTop, bdsInsertRight, bdsInsertBottom] * State <> [] then
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
      InsertIndication := Rect;
      if bdsInsertLeft in State then
      begin
        Dec(InsertIndication.Left, 2);
        InsertIndication.Right := InsertIndication.Left + 2;
      end
      else if bdsInsertTop in State then
      begin
        Dec(InsertIndication.Top);
        InsertIndication.Bottom := InsertIndication.Top + 2;
      end
      else if bdsInsertRight in State then
      begin
        Inc(InsertIndication.Right, 2);
        InsertIndication.Left := InsertIndication.Right - 2;
      end
      else if bdsInsertBottom in State then
      begin
        Inc(InsertIndication.Bottom);
        InsertIndication.Top := InsertIndication.Bottom - 2;
      end;
      Canvas.FillRect(InsertIndication);
      //Canvas.Brush.Color := FillColor;
    end;

    if gboShowCaptions in TButtonGroup(Sender).ButtonOptions then
    begin
      { Avoid clipping the image }
      Inc(TextLeft, TextOffset);
      TextRect.Left := TextLeft;
      TextRect.Right := Rect.Right - 1;
      TextRect.Top := TextTop;
      TextRect.Bottom := Rect.Bottom -1;
      Text := ButtonItem.Caption;
      Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, Text, [tfEndEllipsis]);
    end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
  MBitmap.LoadFromFile('bg.bmp');
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MBitmap.Free;
end;
```

DFM :

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 398
  ClientWidth = 287
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  StyleElements = []
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 5
    Top = 5
    Width = 137
    Height = 388
    Margins.Left = 5
    Margins.Top = 5
    Margins.Right = 5
    Margins.Bottom = 5
    Align = alLeft
    BevelKind = bkFlat
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clWhite
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 0
    StyleElements = [seFont]
    object ButtonGroup1: TButtonGroup
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 4
      Top = 4
      Width = 125
      Height = 378
      Margins.Left = 4
      Margins.Top = 4
      Margins.Right = 4
      Margins.Bottom = 2
      Align = alClient
      BevelInner = bvNone
      BevelOuter = bvNone
      BorderStyle = bsNone
      ButtonOptions = [gboFullSize, gboGroupStyle, gboShowCaptions]
      DoubleBuffered = True
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
      Font.Style = []
      Items = <
        item
          Caption = 'General'
        end
        item
          Caption = 'Display'
        end
        item
          Caption = 'Proofing'
        end
        item
          Caption = 'Save'
        end
        item
          Caption = 'Language'
        end
        item
          Caption = 'Advanced'
        end>
      ParentDoubleBuffered = False
      TabOrder = 0
      OnDrawButton = ButtonGroup1DrawButton
    end
  end
end
```

There is a Panel container in there hosting the TButtonGroup, it is not needed, simply added for visual improvement.

If you want to change the color of the selection at runtime then I suggest using [efg's Hue/Saturation method](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/ChangeHueSaturation.ZIP) to change the Hue of the image, that way the color panel remains but the color will change.

To gain support for VCL Styles simply detach the ButtonGroup1DrawButton Event from the TButtonGroup component, that way the default DrawButton Event can kick in which adds support for that.

Comment: Using VCL Styles means you will not follow the Windows theme

Comment: @Eric, Office 2010 doesn't follow the Windows theme either!

Comment: Both of you are correct :) I think I'll still start with this option, at least for the initial demo/testing code. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, XE2 doesn't implement the StyleElements property and I cannot change TButtonGroup background from a gray color :(

Comment: @gabr, It is possible to do that either through the Vcl Styles Utility or through StyleHooks but I don't think VCL Styles are worth being used on XE2, back then it was a pain to use it. I will be editing my answer soon on how to get the result you want just using the default Windows Theme like you requested.

Comment: @gabr , I've updated my answer now using default painting methods as requested.

Comment: Peter, thanks for all the work you put into this answer! For the time being, I'll go with your approach but most probably I'll change it at some point to use theme painting. (If that happens, I'll post my code here.)

Answer (score 8):

You can use a TListBox with style set to lbOwnerDrawFixed (if the size of the spacing isn't important) or lbOwnerDrawVariable if it is.

You can then handle OnDrawItem & OnMeasureItem accordingly.

Using clWindow will be no problem, however AFAIK the orange color is not part of the Windows theme, but you can obtain something that will match the theme by starting from clHighlight and then applying a hue shift, then lightness shift for the shading.

If your hue shift is constant, it'll automatically adapt to the theme colors.

Sample code (without the HueShift for the orange): drop a TListBox, set lbOwnerDrawFixed, adjust ItemHeight to 28, set font to "Segoe UI" and use the following OnDrawItem

[image: preview]

```
var
   canvas : TCanvas;
   txt : String;
begin
   canvas:=ListBox1.Canvas;
   canvas.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
   canvas.Brush.Color:=clWindow;
   canvas.FillRect(Rect);
   InflateRect(Rect, -2, -2);
   if odSelected in State then begin
      canvas.Pen.Color:=RGB(194, 118, 43);
      canvas.Brush.Color:=RGB(255, 228, 138);
      canvas.RoundRect(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom, 6, 6);
      canvas.Pen.Color:=RGB(246, 200, 103);
      canvas.RoundRect(Rect.Left+1, Rect.Top+1, Rect.Right-1, Rect.Bottom-1, 6, 6);
   end;
   canvas.Font.Color:=clWindowText;
   canvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
   txt:=ListBox1.Items[Index];
   Rect.Left:=Rect.Left+10;
   canvas.TextRect(Rect, txt, [tfLeft, tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter]);
end;
```

If you're going to have more than one such components, it's of course preferable to just subclass TListBox, and if you want anti-aliasing for the RoundRect, GR32 or GDI+ can be used.

Note that for backward compatibility with XP, "Segoe UI" font should be set dynamically, as it's not available in XP (in XP "Arial" is a good fallback, "Tahoma" looks closer but isn't guaranteed to be there)

Comment: It's odd that you comment on another answer that does not adhere to system theme, and also add such an answer yourself

Comment: Such an approach - but using theme drawing function instead of GDI - may indeed be the best approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can owner draw and still follow theme colors, while VCL skins don't follow the theme colors (f.i. if users goes for a dark background, owner draw with clWindow will be dark, while VCL skin will still be white)

Comment: @EricGrange, VCL styles support windows themes just fine hence the presence of the SysColor Object. You can easily modify a VCL theme to adhere to the current windows theme altho that kinda defeats the purpose of using VCL styles in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

We use [TMS Control's **Advanced Poly Pager**](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advpolylist.asp) for this look.  I highly recommend it.  It's a very powerful and flexible set of controls.  Specifically, we use `TAdvPolyList` for our Office-style dialogs with some custom tweaking to the colour scheme.  (Note this is different to their `TAdvOfficePager` which doesn't look nearly as good.  Don't accidentally mix the two up!)

It allows you to:

- Have a category selector on the left
- Is a page control, so is easy to have your controls on pages on the right (the same as a normal page control)
- Shows a visual link between the tab and page, something the Word screenshot you provided doesn't do (Word has a barrier in-between; this control doesn't.  It's a better, more intuitive and well-linked UI deisgn.)
- Will certainly allow you to use color constants like clWindow if you wish, though anything would
- Has a wide variety of items that can go in the left panel, including images, text with images, links, etc.  Your Word screenshot has subtle gray dividing lines separating some of the elements; I'm sure you can do this with this control too, whereas it would be trickier to reliably do with some of the other answers posters have given, such as custom-painting TListBox.
- Looks great!

The images on their site don't really show perfectly how to mimic an Office look, but from these two screenshots (high-res on their site) you should be able to see the sort of things you can achieve:

[image: AdvPolyList Office menu emulation]

and

[image: Nicer menu emulation]

Our menus look similar to the second screenshot but with simple text items (nothing complex like checkboxes and images etc - I think they've put those there just to demonstrate that you can) and uses a colour scheme more like yours, plus we added blue headers to each page.

We bought it a couple of years ago and have never regretted it.  Highly recommended.

Comment: It looks quite nice, however, when I tested it sometime ago I can feel its sluggish (not to a great extent though).

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought you could use two things: a page control for the part on the right.
For the part on the left I'd think you have a few options, the main probably being a GridLayout using 1 column and speed buttons.

Not overly difficult, but a bit messy. You could probably do with a frame to contain the buttons part.

The only difficult bit would be the separation bars, but maybe you could do that by subclassing it and having specific properties.

Regards,

A

Comment: I've thought about the TSpeedButton, but it gets its style from the current theme and is as such usually painted grey on Windows 7. I would have to override/reimplement TSpeedButton.Paint (and at the moment I have no idea how to change existing Paint to paint the button white).

Comment: Why the minus 1? This would work very well, on old and new compilers. If the -1 is because it is viewed as an "old" solution, remember that the software in your DNA is very old, but you still trust it.